# Ubuntu: Application history in gtkwm/gdm?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, history, logging

Is there some way I can track all applications that were opened by a user during a gnome session in ubuntu?

Do gdm/gtkwm keep a history of all applications that were opened in some log file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the Gnome Activity Journal.  I've only read about it, but it might have something you could use in there.

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/01/19/preview-gnome-activity-journal-zeitgeist-on-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: By the looks of it, the gnome activity journal will keep track of the files I accessed, and not the applications I opened which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

No, to my best knowledge there is no way to do this within the desktop or window manager.

But take a look at [gnome deployment guide](http://library.gnome.org/admin/deployment-guide/) for some lockdown options. Maybe one of the kiosk mode options is of some help.

It might be easier to convince [apparmor](http://www.novell.com/linux/security/apparmor/overview.html) or SELinux to provide such a log.